# How to build the body of a request in json format

Tags: java, android, json, httpurlconnection

Here is the request I should call:
[listing library contents](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/list#listing-library-contents)

> GET https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems
>   Content-type: application/json
>   Authorization: Bearer oauth2-token
>   {
>     "pageSize": "100",
>   }

Here's what I tried:

```java
public String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
        String body1 = "{pageSize: 100,}";
        String body2 = "{\"pageSize\": \"100\",}";
        HttpURLConnection request = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            request = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

            request.setRequestMethod("GET");
            request.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            request.setUseCaches(false);
            request.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            request.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            request.setReadTimeout(timeout);
            request.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d", body2.getBytes().length));
            OutputStream outputStream = request.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(body2.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
            request.connect();
            int status = request.getResponseCode();

            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (request != null) {
                try {
                    request.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If I use the GET method I get an error:

> java.net.ProtocolException: method does not support a request body: GET

I tried with POST but without success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: GET with a request body is very unusual and not supported by many HTTP clients. This sounds like a documentation bug and that you're actually meant to use POST not GET. What happened when you tried POST?

Comment: response code = 404

Comment: 404 = resource not found. Are you sure you have the right URL?

Comment: yes because if i don't specify {"pageSize": "100",} it's ok ... except that I only get the first 25 items as specified with GET

Comment: @Joni If I use OkHttp3 ... how do I make the request? with {"pageSize": "100",}

Comment: I don't think that last comma belongs there, try `"{\"pageSize\": \"100\"}"`. I would expect the API to give a different response code, like "400 bad request."

Comment: yes but how to make the requestbody since FormEncodingBuilder () is not in the OkHttp3 library

Comment: This API expects a request body in JSON. What happens if you remove that stray comma and use `"{\"pageSize\": \"100\"}"`?
OkHttp does not include a JSON library. Gson is a popular choice for Android. If you used Retrofit it could make things a lot easier for you.

Comment: same response 404... I don't know retrofit... i will do a try! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to send a param along with this request

You can try this request in postman using this query

https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems?pageSize=100

and pass the token in the authentication section.

Here you can do something like -

```
eg 
URI uri = new URIBuilder("https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems")
          .addParameter("pageSize", 100)
          .build();
```

Suggestion -  Use retrofit for network requests and jackson-databind project for JSON conversions.

Comment: works fine with  https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems?pageSize=100, but I encounter  once more time an issue for dependencies reasons  with new URIBuilder()

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation is wrong and you're supposed to use a POST request instead of GET.

Also there is an error in the documented JSON request body: there is a trailing comma that should not be there. Use the following:

```
String body2 = "{\"pageSize\": \"100\"}";
```